# Intercept (mock) http requests on Node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, browser

I don't know if I'm asking too much, but I want a library to intercept/mock HTTP requests in a isomorphic/progressive way (i.e. works the same on node.js and browser) for unit/behavior tests. Is there such a thing?

I'm building a client for an API and it must work both on server and browser. [Nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) is great but only for Node (as it doesn't work with [Browserify](http://browserify.org), I tried).

I could just mock the library I'll use for requests (such as [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) or [rest](https://github.com/cujojs/rest)). That, however, would lock me in to some library and would require a major refactor of the tests.

My wish is to avoid duplication of tests and avoid the most checks for environment as possible. And to be agnostic of implementation, hence my need to mock the requests.

I'm almost considering making one myself (or at least a glue between two libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at how [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) were doing their tests. They build a mock [Express](http://expressjs.com) server to respond in the way they want and check for matches.

### But how does that work on the browser?

It turns out they were using [Zuul](https://github.com/defunctzombie/zuul) for that.

**Zuul** is a tool that creates an ad-hoc server to run tests in the browser. It supports qunit, mocha, tape and a few other test frameworks. It also accept a mock server to run during the tests. And it runs tests on [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com/), which have a free plan for open source projects.

This is not the solution I expected but it is a solution.

You can look at [my project](https://github.com/flikore/writerstrail-client/tree/f39b3255217e2e09a43d6398fead07e7a31d1e84) to see the proper code (permalink to the tree of the last commit by the time of this answer).